# Offline testing using online PHP database, but without uploading files to server

Tags: php, mysql, database, offline

So here is my dilemma. I wish to test my PHP website offline, but with an online PHP database. I also dont want to upload the files to the server.
Is there a way for me to run them localy in Chrome, but without having to use third-party software like WAMP or XAMPP to create a local MySQL database?
I've tried those, and there are so many errors etc. using them.

Any tips or hidden tricks?

Comment: No, you need a local webserver to test with. WAMP and XAMP are both good and easy to use options. Not sure what you mean by *so many errors* with using them, either one would work well for your needs when configured

Comment: There is a host out there that starts with 000 in their URL.  You can create a full PHP site with mySql database.  Use that for testing.  I wouldn't use it for anything more serious than that.  But for testing, it's really great.

Comment: @mituw16 I tried installing both, however, Apache couldn't start on XAMPP and I ran diagnostics and looked on the error logs. Nothing solved it. So I tried WAMP, and the problem with WAMP is that it didn't allow me to create users to fetch information from the database. I also got a bunch of error messages just by typping in a PHP statement like `if($_GET['page'] == 1){ }`. Any tips?

Comment: We won't be able to help you get this installed without knowing your development environment, FWIW, I've never had a single issue with doing a basic install of WAMP. You might have more luck on super user or server fault than here for trying to get WAMP configured.

Comment: @mituw16 Okai, thank you. I will try and see if I can get a response there. I will be happy to accept your answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offline testing using an online PHP Database and WITHOUT uploading the files to the server is impossible. You have to use a local database in order to test PHP websites offline.

There are several great softwares that can help you do this easily.
*WAMP* and *XAMPP* are just some of these.